# How does SUSY differ from just having standard model (SM) particles in new Lorentz Group representations?

Tags: field-theory, standard-model, representation-theory, supersymmetry, mssm

Under the standard model (SM), it is the irreducible representations of the Lorentz group which allows us to classify particles according to their spin. We can then further label particles using the irreducible representations of the SM gauge groups, meaning for instance we would say that a left-handed electron exists in the $(1/2,0)$ representation of the Lorentz group, and in the ($\textbf{1}$,$\textbf{2}$,$\textrm{-1}$) representations of the $SU(3)\times SU(2)_{L}\times U(1)_{Y}$ SM gauge groups.

In SUSY, one defines a new operator that relates Bosonic states to Fermionic states and vice-versa. My confusion though is in trying to understand what exactly this operator is doing. Is it simply relating one representation of the Lorentz group to another, and acts like a ladder operator to move particles from one to the other? If I were to for instance propose a new particle that existed in the $(0,0)$ representation of the Lorentz group and shared all the same quantum numbers as the SM electron, would this new particle be equivalent to the selectron proposed in SUSY? If it would not be the same, in what way would it be different?

Comment: it's not enough to just introduce a general scalar to pair it with the electron, both must transform as a SUSY doublet, and the action must be supersymmetry invariant,  which fixes the interactions to an extent.

Comment: at the SUSY standards model level, you can break SUSY explicitly (by so-called soft SUSY breaking terms), but those breaking terms must ultimately come from a UV completion of the SM (supergravity and beyond), where SUSY is broken spontaneously.

Comment: Yes, I recognize that SUSY must realistically be broken, however for this question I wanted to ignore those details and pretend that we live in a world where SUSY is not broken. Can you clarify a bit of why both particles must transform as a SUSY doublet? Or is that just because I mentioned 2 particles, and if we wanted it could also be a SUSY triplet by introducing more new particles? I understand Lorentz reps and SM gauge reps, and I am really just trying to understand how SUSY relates to both of those.

Comment: This should be part of your introductory SUSY text. For N=1 supersymmetry, two states differing in spin by 1/2 are connected by susy, and share external quantum numbers, commuting with SUSY.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry#Extended_supersymmetry) for how @Kosm's doublet point generalizes to extended ($N\ge2$) supersymmetry.